# Formula Index Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on a computer vision project and need to implement the formula on the bottom of page 13 of 
http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~donovan/stabilization/opticalflow.pdf

My question pertains to the use of two different index variables i and j by the author. As far as I can tell the sums are always over the number of rows of Matrix A. I therefore don't see the point of using a second index variable. Normally you would only use j if you were summing over the number of columns.

Given that my implementation of this formula treating occurrences of i and j indifferently (i.e. summing over number of rows) does not deliver the desired result, there must be some reason for the use of j that I am missing.

Any feedback is welcome.

Warm regards,

Mark